# Saving multiple-line field in the database showing as one-line in the view

Tags: php, mysql, string, laravel

First , please note that I'm aware that I should use `{!! code here !!}` to parse HTML in Laravel. 
But this is not the problem.

I have a textarea where people write in a description about a product they want to sell , once that saved to the database in `phpmyadmin` I can see that the input is of multiple lines .

However , when I do `{!! $product->description !!}` in my view it shows all the `description` in single line.

I found a workaround for it but I think there must be a better method to fix this.

the work around that I found is to do the following to replace the new lines with `<br>` HTML tag:

```
$d = $product->description;

$d = str_replace("\r\n","<br>", $d); // for Windows
$d = str_replace("\n","<br>", $d); // for Linux-like operating systems
```

And then I echo `$d`
and it works just fine , is there any better approach to solve this problem ?

I am using Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a better idea for you.
saving a multiple lines with \r or \n doesn't have any problem. Just use it as it is.
then for show the text with line breaks use the line blow in your laravel blade.

```
{!! nl2br($product->description) !!}
```

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: it works ! basically nl2br function converts the new lines to <br> tags automatically , am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "nl2br" for that
The nl2br() function inserts HTML line breaks in front of each newline (\n) in a string.

```
<p>{!! nl2br($product->description) !!}</p>
```

Refer [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)